# Is there an easy way to add a decorator to >1000 functions in python? (without manually doing it)

Tags: python, function, pytest, decorator

I am writing a python script which required me to fail certain tests if a particular decorator is not added , I want this change to reflect in all further pytests which are added to me repo , without affecting the current ones.

> 1000 tests in my current repo are failing , i want to add the decorator to all these tests without having to do the manual effort , is there some way where i can add a condition and add the decorator to all those functions.

i dont need help figuring out the condition , just an easy way to add decorator to all my functions.

if myCondition:
add decorator to functions satisfying that condn

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to add the decorator to all new tests, all existing failing tests, both, or something else? Part of the question seems to ask about new tests only (that's "easy", just add it as you write the new tests), part seems to ask about modifying existing tests conditionally (harder; gotta get the names of all the tests, and, assuming it's a one-time deal, just script a find-and-replace for those tests, probably based on regexes; if it's a >1 time deal, maybe some metaprogramming to make a `list` of the ones to change and apply it at runtime).

Comment: @ShadowRanger hey , i want to add the decorator to existing failing tests. There are a huge number of tests which are failing(~1300) , to fix them a decorator needs to be added to all.
I have a list of failing tests(along with test class) in my jenkins pipeline , i want some way to retrieve the failing 'test classes' from there and add a decorator to the test class rather than adding it to each test. (this will simplify our work)